# How to store values from an async task inside sharedpreferences and use it in another activities

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

How can I store a string in shared-preferences that I've generated it inside a private async class and then use it in another activity?

```
    public class Login extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener  {


SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login); 
     LB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
     LB.setOnClickListener(this);
public void onClick(View view){
switch (view.getId()){

    case R.id.loginbutton:
    new LongOperation().execute("");

    break;


    }
    }
public class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{ //string, void, string was added automatically

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         SoapPrimitive result =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
         String Something = result.toString();
         editor.putString("sessionid",Something);
catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(); }



        return null; 


    } // closing bracket of do in background

}
```

When I try to run the app, it shut downs, thats the error i get in the log cat

```
01-30 08:22:22.027: D/AndroidRuntime(11202): Shutting down VM
01-30 08:22:22.027: W/dalvikvm(11202): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4178ada0)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202): Process: com.datacom.caservicedesk, PID: 11202
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.datacom.caservicedesk/com.datacom.caservicedesk.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:164)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5350)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:185)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at com.datacom.caservicedesk.Login.<init>(Login.java:53)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
01-30 08:22:22.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11202):    ... 11 more
01-30 08:26:13.387: W/ActivityThread(11709): Application com.datacom.caservicedesk can be debugged on port 8100...
01-30 08:26:13.407: D/AndroidRuntime(11709): Shutting down VM
01-30 08:26:13.407: W/dalvikvm(11709): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4178ada0)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709): Process: com.datacom.caservicedesk, PID: 11709
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.datacom.caservicedesk/com.datacom.caservicedesk.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:164)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5350)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:185)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at com.datacom.caservicedesk.Login.<init>(Login.java:53)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
01-30 08:26:13.417: E/AndroidRuntime(11709):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: The same way as you 'normally' would store it. You could do it in onPostExecute of the task but in doInBackgroud is ok too.

Comment: i tried doing that but whenever i run the app it shuts down! I had this inside my oncreate                                        `public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    static SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor; `                                and then i had this inside my doitinbackground                                        `String Something = result.toString(); editor.putString("sessionid",Something);`

Comment: And that's all? `settings` not initiated? `settings` null? Where did you use `PREFS_NAME`? You can see all errors in the LogCat. Post it here please.

Comment: On the other activity i had this                               `public classCreateRequest extends Activity {
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   String sessionid = preferences.getString("sessionid","");
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_request);
  TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
  result.setText(sessionid.toString());`

Comment: We are not interested in your other activity as long as you can not save and your app crashes. So lets first resolve the save problem. Don't put your code in a comment as it is difficultt to read as you can see. Post it in a separate block. Now concentrate on the saving until that is ok.

Comment: thanks for the help, I've edited my post with my current code, ignore my code in comments please

Comment: As you can see in the log there is a `NullPointerException` caused by Login.java:55. Which code line is that? (double click in the logcat on that line and you will land on line 55). But i see already: `settings` and `editor `are not initialised. (That you did better in second activity! Look!).

Comment: `SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` I've deleted settings and I followed the third answer on this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values). I've updated my code above and the error in the log cat I dunno why my app shuts down, please help!

Comment: You still have a null pointer exception on Login.java. This time on line 53.  What is on that line?